# Substitute n in [x|x<-[1..n]]

Tags: haskell, monads

```
test n = (sum s)*4+2*(n-1)*((l')^2)-2*(n-1)*(l')
    where 
      p =sort $[ m | a<-[1..(n-1)],b<-[1..(n-1)],let m= (b/a), (a^2+b^2< (n^2))]
      l'= length p
      s = (product a) : next a (group p)
        where 
          a = [(n-1),2*(l')+(n-2)] 
          next [x,y] (z:z':zs) = case (null zs) of
            False -> (x')*(y')*l : next [x',y'] (z':zs)
            True -> (x')*(y')*l :[]
            where 
              l  = length z
              x' = x+l
              y' = y-length z'
```

Why does the above code give the following error:

> No instance for (Fractional Int) arising from a use of ‘/’
>      In the expression: (b / a)
>
> In an equation for ‘m’: m = (b / a)
>
> In the second argument of ‘($)’, namely
>
> ```
>  ‘[m |
>     a <- [1 .. (n - 1)],
>      b <- [1 .. (n - 1)],
>      let m = (b / a),
>     (a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 < (n ^ 2))]’
> ```

But when I substituted `n=3` in the code by hand:

```
test' = (sum s)*4+2*(3-1)*((l')^2)-2*(3-1)*(l')
    where 
      p = sort $[ m | a<-[1..(3-1)],b<-[1..(3-1)],let m= (b/a), (a^2+b^2< (3^2))]
      l'= length p
      s = (product a) : next a (group p)
        where 
          a = [(3-1),2*(l')+(3-2)] 
          next [x,y] (z:z':zs) = case (null zs) of
            False -> (x')*(y')*l : next [x',y'] (z':zs)
            True -> (x')*(y')*l :[]
            where 
              l  = length z
              x' = x+l
              y' = y-length z'
```

Then it can be run in GHCi; what is happening?

Comment: You may find it interesting to know that one thing type theorists typically prove about their systems is that beta reduction respects typing; that is, if `(\x -> e) e'` can be given type `t`, then `e[e'/x]` (the term where we replace `x` with `e'` everywhere in `e`) can also be given type `t`. However, the reverse is generally not true: `e[e'/x]` may have more types than `(\x -> e) e'`. In particular when `e'` is polymorphic -- as `3` is in your example -- but is forced to be monomorphic by function application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you typed `n`, you forced it to become `Int` with your expressions. Thus, `b` and `a` became `Int`s, which became problematic in `a/b`.

When you wrote `3`, the literal being polymorphic allowed some expressions to use `Int`, and some to use some other `Fractional a => a`. The `3`s used across that function are simply different values.

Creating a different value such as `nP = fromIntegral n` [should allow you to use n in every context](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93fd1ffffc72eb06), because `nP` shouldn't become rigidized by any expression.

Comment: Last sentence is true only if you write a type signature for `nP` (or disable the monomorphism restriction).

Comment: @ReidBarton I guess monomorphism restriction was set up precisely to avoid doing that accidentally.

Comment: This answers the question, but doesn't seem to get at the various problems with this code, such as the fact that using non-integral numbers in ranges is rather shady.

Comment: @dfeuer True. I can't expand it right now but will try in the future. I encourage you to write your own answer, though; I admit I only focused on the "what", no the "why" part,